# r: Assigning labels to leafs and rectangles to dendrogram using dendextend possible?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, dendrogram, dendextend

I want to plot dendrogram with for dataframe `data` with 7 columns (2 Factor, 5 num). The first column is containing the names of 7 different countries and in the following columns I have collected data for different parameters (like population, GDP etc.) characterizing each country. In the last column a factor variable assigns which continent the respective country belongs to.

Here is the data

```
structure(list(Country = structure(c(5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
3L), .Label = c("Brazil", "Chile", "China", "France", "Germany", 
"India", "Netherlands"), class = "factor"), GDP = c(0.46, 0.57, 
0.75, 0.56, 0.28, 0.88, 1), Population = c(0.18, 0.09, 0.54, 
0.01, 0.02, 0.17, 0.84), Birth.rate = c(87.21, 18.34, 63.91, 
14.21, 5.38, 51.19, 209.26), Income = c(43.89, 18.23, 63.91, 
12.3, 0.1, 14.61, 160.82), Savings = c(43.32, 0.11, 0, 1.91, 
5.29, 36.58, 50.38), Continent = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Asia", "Europe", "South America"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Country", 
"GDP", "Population", "Birth.rate", "Income", "Savings", "Continent"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Now the dendrogram which I want to obtain should have the following characteristics:

1. the leave-labels should be colored according to there continent membership
2. the leaves should be labeled according to the respective country (NOT numbers)
3. there should be rectangles around the clusters

I have tried the `dendextend` package which can be found here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#setting-a-dendrograms-branches but 2. and 3. of the above characteristics seem not to work together at the same time. My code looks like this (after having normalized `data` to `norm`)

```
#color codes for continents
regionCodes = c(rep("Europe",3), rep("South America", 2), rep("Asia",2), )
rownames(data) = make.unique(regionCodes)
colorCodes = c(Europe="blue", South America="yellow", Asia="red")

#dendrogram generation and plot
dc = as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(norm), method="complete"))
labels_colors(dc) = colorCodes[regionCodes][order.dendrogram(dc)]
labels(dc) = data$Country
labels_cex(dc) = .7
dc %>% plot
dc %>% rect.dendrogram(k=4, border = 8, lty = 5, lwd = 2)
```

But it produces the following error

> Error in data$Country : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Can you help me?

Comment: @Tal Galili: do you have any advice?